# how to maintian php multidimensional array values..and use it in the same page for every form submit

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new to `PHP`. I'm trying to develop a quiz kind of application in `PHP` and `MySQL`. with 1 fetch, I fetched say 10 questions along with its answer and answer options and storing in php multidimensional array. My aim is to display 1 question at a time and the form will be submitted. The problem I'm facing is, after submitting 1st question, I'm losing the multidimensional array values which has further questions to be displayed. I tried putting that value in hidden field in html and accessing back in php from `$_POST[]`. But I do not get the array values.

Now my question is:-

1. Is my design correct to fetch all questions @ once and trying to manage in the same PHP file? I do not mind reloading the page when user clicks submit.

2.What should I do to maintain the array value in PHP for as many requests as possible? I did googled to see how to store array in hidden field, but I cant store that way for each question and answer. It'll make my code cumbersome. here's my code:

In my php file, this is how am populating array.

```
$setofquestions[$row['question_id']] = array(
            "question" => $row['question'],
            "answer"   => $row['answer'],
            "answeroptions" => $row['answer_options']);
```

I'm accessing the hidden field.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $answerselected = $_POST['ansfromUser'];
   $setofquestions = $_POST['questionset'];
}
```

In my html file,I'm giving like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="questionset" value="<?php echo $setofquestions;?>" />
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To carry forward the values, you should save the values in session.

Rather than this approach you can run a select query on each page submission. Because while showing the first question it is no point to carry the all other nine questions together.

If you want you can show all ten question in a page but hiding other question usings css display property and upon answering each question you can show  / hide blocks using jQuery.

Comment: I would prefer this show/hide blocks in jQuery. Let me see how that works. Thanks for letting me know this option as I'm new to jQuery too..